# CSS div gutters not inc. in scroll/container

Tags: html, css, layout, position, overflow

My site is centrally aligned in a div container @980px width. I need a div gutter on the left and one on the right for clickable banner ads but i don't want them within the scrollable container.

To explain more clearly, if the screen res goes down to 980px I don't want to see the ads or a scroller - just my container. If it goes down less than 980px I want to see a scroller (as I do now) for the center container.

The gutters are only for wider screen users and should not be included in the scroll. I don't want to use media queries as I want part of the ad to show either side if the screen resolution is nearly wide enough.

I'm stuck how to do this. Do I position absolute the container and position relative the gutters? Do I need to use overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezy2J/1/

Be aware that unless the iframe is wide enough the banners won't show in the fiddle, so make sure to resize the html iframe in the fiddle.

You can use `position: relative` on the container and then `position: absolute` on the banners to get them to stay outside the container.

I've used media queries to hide, show and resize the banners (drag the iframe width for the HTML).  You'd probably use `display: block` and `display: none` for compatibility instead of `opacity: 0` and `opacity: 1` but it looks nicer for these purposes!

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly close - as you reduce width the left gutter ad and right disappear off screen in equal amounts (perfect) ...but... I get the scroller instantly when left, center and right begin to go off screen but the scroll only reveals more of the right div. This would be unfair to the left advertiser. I only want scroll for <980px ...

Comment: Figured it out, using that fiddle with a surround div fixed it:
<div style="min-width:980px; width:100%; overflow-x:hidden;">

Answer (score 0):

something like **[that](http://jsfiddle.net/2Wwgx/)**?

learn about `position: absolute`
dont forget about `position: relative` on parent container